# Creating JSPs with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, user-interface

I'm trying to create several JSPs, and I was told that what most people do, is open notepad and hardcode the whole thing in. I come from the origins of C#, so that option is somewhat foreign to me :)

I did try to do several complex components by hand in Java. It took quite a bit of time (mostly with arrangements) but I was able to do it.

My question is, will I be able to create JSPs inside of Eclipse and will all the UI components that I will implement be there as I positioned them?

I'm asking because I found an Eclipse plugin (http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html) that allows me to drag and drop components (C# style :D) and I needed to know if it is worth downloading, because if I still have to hardcode the JSP's UI in, the download time will be a waste (slow speed here).

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean with drag and drop components in C#, but if you actually meant ASP.NET(-MVC), then you should actually be looking at JSF, not JSP. The JSP is more the counterpart of "Classic ASP". For JSF there are plenty of visual editors available.

Comment: By drag and drop, I meant Visual Studio where you can create your own application by dragging a component (ie. button) into your form.
You may be right about JSFs. Can swing and .awt libraries be used to create JSFs, or are they only intended for application? Or do I have to get a JSF visual editor (from the preview, it looks like Dreamweaver, which looks promising)?

Comment: Swing and AWT are desktop components, not web components, so forget about it when developing a web application, unless you intend to develop a Java Applet or Web Start application which you in turn can embed in an arbitrary web page using HTML `<applet>` or `<object>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a `jsp` page  and <kbd>right click</kbd> on the editor and go to open with.
2. Select <kbd>Web Page Editor</kbd> and you will have the design view opened.
3. On the top right corner you will have an arrow. Click on the arrow and you will have elements to drag and drop on the editor.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for it a long time

Answer (score 0):

1. I think almost nobody uses notepad to create JSP's. The editing is done in text mode in IDE's or comparable tools.
2. I agree with @BalusC, JSP's don't have good support for drag and drop development (like Visual Studio), although there tools like Dreamweaver which had some support to create the HTML structure in a WYSYWYG environment. I would not recommend these kind of tools for JSP but it's your choice.
3. The plugin you mention is **not for JSP's** and any of the alternatives it does support won't be quick to learn.
4. As @BalusCmentions, JSF's is an alternative for which there are some visual editors. You might want to look into that but you'd need to do some research as JSF is an standard and there are several implementations and related tools around. There are plugins for JSF support in Eclipse.

All in all I think you need to read further on Java web development and the alternatives that exist.

Comment: Alexey is the OP itself, see also the blue highlighted name in the comment.

Comment: I don't know how I overlooked it, but could this possibly be it? http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/index.html . Cause at the time I was looking for a plug-in that would make applications, but is this for JSPs? I don't see it explicitly mentioning it, but maybe I'm not reading it properly.

Comment: No, is not for JSP's. GWT is a toolkit to make web pages from Java, (without JSP's). http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html